# Is it possible to use EL3 on an AllWinner SoC (R18)?

Tags: arm, firmware, soc

I have been looking for a cheap development board to play around with ARMv8 EL3 mode in the interest of writing a monitor. I stumbled across the [PINE64](https://www.pine64.org/?page_id=46823) recently and it seemed like a great fit. It used the AllWinner R18 ARMv8 SoC and had JTAG support. However, I began searching about and discovered trace comments about essentially being locked out of AllWinner SoCs at EL3.

According to the PINE64 [wiki page](http://linux-sunxi.org/Pine64#BSP), the SoC's ROM will look for payloads over USB-OTG or an attached SDcard. Lots of talk about EL2/1 during this time.

However, there is also [this mention](http://linux-sunxi.org/Pine64#Boot_sequence) of the ROM loading from sector 16 of the SDcard and executing it in aarch32 mode. It does not mention the ELx level, but perhaps it is from EL3? Unlikely, unless that was their intent. Does anyone know for certain?

Also, I've been unable to find an AllWinner R18 datasheet. I am unfamiliar with the company: do they typically require an NDA for this information? Older SoCs do appear online.

---

I have pending support emails to both companies at the moment, I just wanted to probe the community as well for real experience with AllWinner SoCs.

As an aside, and this one might go against the rules here, does anyone have experience with a decent ARMv8 development board that is debuggable and has EL3 support? I've found the [Juno](https://developer.arm.com/products/system-design/development-boards/juno-development-board), but it's expensive and I do not need all the extra features.

More community conversation about the AllWinner SoCs and whether or not they support running user code in EL3. Several people chime in and report conflicting information. https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13397994

Comment: upvote for well written and interesting question

Comment: @jsotola, Oops. Hmm. Assuming zero indexing then _sector 16_ would be the _15th sector_ (assuming a zeroth sector). Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes, that is what i mean ...... i have no idea if there zero indexing is used